# How to write algorithm of distribution amounts

Tags: algorithms

I have an array of N integer values, and I need to sum elements and distribute these sums by equal parts in the range from 150 to 250, but without to mix indexes. For example {50,100,50,250,200,49, 100} will be (50+100+50), (250), (200+49), (100). This is the best solution here. But I can't write the optimal algorithm for this case and I have a result with a small amount in the middle or a big number in the end. But I need the most optimal result. Does anyone have any ideas <strike>is it possible</strike> how to write this distribute algorithm?

Update: I can't move values to another position. If I have 50 at start I should to summarize it with the nearest values until I reach the desired range 150-250 or until exceed it.

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: What does "without to mix indecies" mean?

Comment: surely the answer you give in your example is wrong

Comment: it should be (50+100), 250, 200, (100+50+49)

Comment: Please use the [Contact Us](/contact) forms to have your accounts merged so that you can edit your question and reply on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe the requirements more exactly. I'm trying to guess your requirements and reword them as I understand them:

- The task is to find sublists of your given list which cover adjacent indexes ("without to mix indexes").
- Each sublist should have a sum between 150 and 250 (is that a hard requirement, or what are the rules if it can't be met?).
- You want to find an optimal solution (how is a solution determined to be better than another?)

Your example doesn't match these requirements, as the last sublist has a sum of 100 which is outside of the allowable range. This makes it hard to decide whether my interpretation is correct.

To change the sum and optimality requirement into something that is solvable and decidable, I'd suggest to change it to "each subarray sum should be close to 200" and "the total quality of a solution is determined by the sum of the squares of the differences between each subarray sum and 200" (least error squares method).

This would change the last two arrays in your example from (200,49),(100) to (200),(49,100) as the sum of error squares is 49^2 + 100^2 in the first case and 0^2 + 51^2 in the second case which is clearly "better" even though the last array is still not within the required bounds.

Before I try to sketch an algorithm (which is pretty tedious typing on a phone) you should work on the formulation of your requirements so we're sure we're talking about the same problem.